# cartopy + networkx: zorder is not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, z-order, cartopy

I need to generate a map using `cartopy` and plot some data over it (using `networkx`). I am able to do it, but `networkx` objects are behind the map. I am trying to force the order of the layers using `zorder` but... it is not working :(

My only idea is to add some transparency to the `cartopy` geometries, but it does not look nice at all... (in this example it does not look so bad, but with my whole data, it looks terrible)

Any ideias on how to force the order?

Here is my code:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io import shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

paises = ['Portugal', 'France', 'Canada', 'Brazil', 'Kazakhstan']
cidades = ['Aveiro', 'Ust-Kamenogorsk', 'Manaus']
links = [('Aveiro', 'Ust-Kamenogorsk'), 
         ('Manaus', 'Ust-Kamenogorsk'),
         ('Aveiro', 'Manaus')]
position = {'Aveiro': (-8.65, 40.6),
            'Manaus': (-60.0, -3.1),
            'Ust-Kamenogorsk': (82.6, 49.97)}

# map using cartopy:
shapename = 'admin_0_countries'
countries_shp = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='110m',
                                    category='cultural', name=shapename)

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0.0, globe=None))
ax.set_global()

for country in shpreader.Reader(countries_shp).records():    
    nome = country.attributes['name_long']
    if nome in paises:
        i = paises.index(nome)
        artist = ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                           facecolor='yellow',
                           #alpha=0.5,
                           zorder=10)
    else:
        artist = ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                           facecolor='0.9',
                           zorder=10)

# add some data over the cartopy map (using networkx):                              
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(cidades)
G.add_edges_from(links)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, position, node_size=20, nodelist=cidades, zorder=20)
edges=nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, position, edgelist=links, zorder=20)

plt.show()
```

And this is the image I get: [image: zorder not working with networkx over cartopy]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happened is that your `zorder=20` doesn't do anything; it got ignored as you can see in their source code. What `networkx` do in [their `draw_networkx_edges` code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_edges) is:

```
def draw_networkx_edges(G, pos,
    ...
    edge_collection.set_zorder(1)  # edges go behind nodes
    ...
```

in [their `draw_networkx_nodes` code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_nodes) is:

```
def draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos,
    ...
    node_collection.set_zorder(2)
    ...
```

Now, the solution is straightforward:

- If you set `zorder` in `add_geometries` to `1`, nodes will then be in front of the map because it's zorder 2. But edges are still behind the map because it's zorder 1.
- Now the real better solution is to get both node_collection and edge_collection first:

  ```
  nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, position, node_size=20, nodelist=cidades)
  edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, position, edgelist=links)
  ```

  Then `set_zorder` for both nodes and edges:

  ```
  nodes.set_zorder(20)
  edges.set_zorder(20)
  ```

Comment: perfect! thank you... I should look for answers in the source code next time :)

Answer (score 3):

If you set the zorder of the shapes you add to the map to 0, everything works as expected.

```
ax.add_geometries(..., zorder=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach

```
# Sort the nodes by degree
sorted_nodes = sorted(G.nodes, key=lambda x: G.degree(x))

# Draw edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.4, edge_color='gray', arrows=False, zorder=0)

# Draw nodes and labels with zorder based on the degree
for node in sorted_nodes:
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=[node], node_color='skyblue', node_size=node_sizes[node], zorder=G.degree[node], ax=ax)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels={node: node}, font_size=9, font_color='black', bbox=def_bbox_props, zorder=G.degree[node] + 1, ax=ax)
```